# Dynamic method call is case-sensitive

Tags: dynamic, abap

Minimal working example:

```
CLASS lcl_some_class DEFINITION. ""// <-- this is obviously lower case
  PUBLIC SECTION.
    CLASS-METHODS some_static_method. ""// <-- this is obviously lower case
  PROTECTED SECTION.
  PRIVATE SECTION.
ENDCLASS.
CLASS lcl_some_class IMPLEMENTATION.
  METHOD some_static_method.
    " nothing
  ENDMETHOD.
ENDCLASS.
END-OF-SELECTION.

DATA: lc_class_name_upper  TYPE string VALUE 'LCL_SOME_CLASS',
      lc_class_name_lower  TYPE string VALUE 'lcl_some_class',
      lc_method_name_upper TYPE string VALUE 'SOME_STATIC_METHOD',
      lc_method_name_lower TYPE string VALUE 'some_static_method'.

CALL METHOD LCL_SOME_CLASS=>SOME_STATIC_METHOD. ""ok
CALL METHOD (lc_class_name_upper)=>(lc_method_name_upper). ""ok

CALL METHOD lcl_some_class=>SOME_STATIC_METHOD. ""ok
CALL METHOD (lc_class_name_lower)=>(lc_method_name_upper). ""failure

CALL METHOD LCL_SOME_CLASS=>some_static_method. ""ok
CALL METHOD (lc_class_name_upper)=>(lc_method_name_lower). ""failure

CALL METHOD lCl_SoMe_ClAsS=>sOmE_sTaTiC_mEtHoD. ""ok
```

I expected the lines with comment "failure" to behave exactly like the corresponding lines above: To be case-insentive. But instead they fail with one of the following messages:

> **`CX_SY_DYN_CALL_ILLEGAL_CLASS / DYN_CALL_METH_CLASS_NOT_FOUND`**
>
> en: The class could not be found during the dynamic method call.
>
> de: Die Klasse beim dynamischen Methodenaufruf konnte nicht gefunden werden.
>
> **`CX_SY_DYN_CALL_ILLEGAL_METHOD / DYN_CALL_METH_NOT_FOUND`**
>
> en: The method could not be found during the dynamic call.
>
> de: Die Methode konnte beim dynamischen Aufruf nicht gefunden werden.

Is there a way to make the dynamic call case-**in**sensitive (except for the obvious converting the strings to upper case)?

Comment: I think you've already given the answer. As far as I know you need to convert the strings to upper case.

Comment: Get your hex to string converter out at DB level and look at REPOSRC and REPOLOAD . get used to it, ABAP compiles in upper case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The official ABAP documentation of [CALL METHOD - dynamic_meth](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_753_index_htm/7.53/en-US/index.htm?file=abapcall_method_meth_ident_dyna.htm) is straight forward, concerning `(class_name)=>(meth_name)` and `(class_name)=>meth`:

> *class_name expects a character-like field that must contain the name of a class in **uppercase letters** when the statement is executed*

I don't see any solution to make the kernel convert the name to upper case itself.

NB: I don't see why it is a problem to convert yourself the name to upper case before doing the dynamic call.