# CALL METHOD with dynamic method name, RuntimeException

Tags: abap

I try to demonstrate a `CALL METHOD` statement with dynamic method name on a 7.40 system.  I use the following test code and get an ABAP Runtime Error in line 27.  The Error Analysis in the Description of Exception states `... in the class LCL, the method "m" could not be found.`  But the standalone method call succeeds in calling `m`.

```
REPORT ZUTEST10.
CLASS lcl DEFINITION.
  PUBLIC SECTION.
    METHODS m.
ENDCLASS.
CLASS lcl IMPLEMENTATION.
  METHOD m.
    write / 'success'.
  ENDMETHOD.
ENDCLASS.

START-OF-SELECTION.

DATA oref TYPE REF TO lcl.
CREATE OBJECT oref.
oref->m( ).                " works fine

DATA name TYPE c VALUE 'm'.
CALL METHOD oref->(name).  " <-- Runtime Error
```

Comment: see also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59034143/dynamic-method-call-is-case-sensitive

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the background all method names are uppercase, so you have to call the method like this:

```
DATA name TYPE c VALUE 'M'.
```

On the other hand you can catch this exception, so the program won't dump, even if the method does not exist:

```
  TRY.
      CALL METHOD oref->(name).
    CATCH cx_sy_dyn_call_illegal_method
          INTO DATA(lx_illegal_method).
      "handle illegal method call
  ENDTRY.
```

Comment: Indeed, with upper-case `M`, the test code executes.  The ABAP Keyword Documentation mentions the case requirement jsut for classes, not for methods.

Comment: @UlrichScholz uppercase is overall: classes, methods, tables, structures, etc.

Comment: It seems that it was inadvertently removed from documentation in ABAP 7.50. It was [there in 7.40](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_740_index_htm/7.40/en-US/index.htm?file=abapcall_method_meth_ident_dyna.htm): `These names are used to specify methods dynamically. meth_name and class_name expect character-like fields, which must contain the name of a method or a class in uppercase when the statement is executed`

Comment: @SandraRossi in 7.51 is back: "meth_name expects a character-like field that must contain the name of a method when the statement is executed." https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_751_index_htm/7.51/en-US/abapcall_method_meth_ident_dyna.htm

Comment: "in uppercase" is missing ;-)